# eigen values inside unit circle

Tags: linear-algebra

I need help in proving that eigen values of matrix $A$ are inside unit circle. The details of $A$ are given below.

Diagonal of $A$ is zero, and $ 1\ge a_{ij} \ge 0, i\neq j$.

Row sum of $A$ is $1$ (for all rows, except the first)

(Only) First row is all zero.

If the first row is not zero and has row-sum equal to $1$, then I get eigen values, $\lambda_i \leq 1$ (gersgorin disk). But with first row zero, numerically I always get $\lambda_i \lt 1$.

I have tried using $Ax=x$, with $x$ being vector of ones, but again i am unable to prove that $(A-I)$ is invertible. (proving using contradiction; let $\lambda=1$, then $Ax=x$, $ = \gt$ $(A-I)x=0$ )

Comment: Why would you want to prove $\;Ax=x\;$ with whatever? What you need to show is that there is some vector $\;x\;$ and some element $\;z\in S^1\;$ s.t. $\;Ax=zx\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio, sorry i didn't write correctly. done some editing now. waiting for answer, :)

Answer (score 2):

It is not true that all eigenvalues are less than $1$.

Consider $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then $A$ has the eigenvalues $0, 1, -1$ but satisfies your constraints.

The matrix
$$B=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\frac12 & \frac12 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0&0 & 0 & 1 \\
0&0 & 1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
has eigenvalues $0,\frac12, 1, -1$ and no column that is entirely zero.

Maybe you need at least two nonzero entries in every row?

Comment: i have checked the detail of $A$ matrix, I should have written in my question that no column is (entirely zero) and no row is entirely zero, except the first row.